# Where would you send developers that want to learn .NET?

Tags: .net, resources

It can be extreme beginners or more experienced developers that used to code in a language like C, Perl, etc. and that wants to develop a desktop software in .NET (no ASP.NET then).

I'm looking for online resources that will help them understand .NET Framework and learn how to code very simple applications.

What I'm looking is content that you could find in "Microsoft Visual Basic .Net Programming for the Absolute Beginner" but online. So no book, no training. Only online resources.

Clarifications:

- there is no need for them to understand how .NET works. If they can design VERY simple application with textboxes and buttons, it's OK.
- I can't tell them: use google. They are customers that may want to develop extension for a product I'm working on. I must point them to useful resources.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: I would clearly send them to http://stackoverflow.com :)

Comment: cody, I do that very often ;) StackOverflow is a revolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommened the official docs:

- [Visual Basic.Net Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/default.aspx)

And always learning spot:

- [The MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Will send them to read answers on this question. :)

But on the serious notes, Instead of having them to understand the tid-bits of CLR and how it all works together, I will prefer them to get their hands on to [any .net language] either C# or VB, preferbly C#. For this I'd ask them read **Begining C#/VB 2005/2008** and start writing simple programs on it. As they read and learn more , they'll have questions "how it works" and then show them resources that will take them yet further. In my opinion **there's no point in explaining CTS, CLS fundas to a .Net beginer**. From my experience, I'd have them start with something that they can easily learn and understand because this will create an interest and confidence in them. **Eventually they'll come to a point where they'll have right questions and know where to look for the right answers**. That's how it works.

Comment: I agree. I updated my question to clarify that point.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's introduction stuff for the Express versions is usually quite basic: [Visual Basic Guided Tour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90h82b3x%28VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

http://asp.net  Lots of tutorials from basic onwards.

Comment: no AS.NET, it's in the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would send them to their computers and ask them to build a sample application. It's their job to figure out how. Google will surely help them.

Comment: In my experience this makes them *somehow* get it to work. That doesn't mean they do it *good* or *right*. But then, this may be enough for Pierre, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the person. If they are experienced they should know how they learn best:

- Read a book
- Training course
- Trail an error with Bing/Google/SO/Forums/...

(or at least what is the right mix for them).

For those who don't know: training course.

(Note there are various training companies who do online courses.)

Comment: No book, no training course. I'm looking for online resources.